# Can I use custom colour profiles with ImageMagick on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, imagemagick

I'm having trouble preparing RGB previews of primarily-CMYK PDFs with Imagemagick on Heroku. I'm using IM's `convert` command, and the image (of the first page of the source PDF) is extracted fine, and saved fine, but the colour conversion is terrible.

On my dev machine, the colour is really saturated and horrible. On Heroku, I get a very odd black-and-white image - almost like only one of the colour channels has been brought over.

I've worked out that this can be fixed by providing colour profiles for the conversion. I've found open-source colour profiles, added them to my project, and this works fine on my dev machine. On Heroku, the convert command can't find the colour profiles.

This is the `convert` command:

`convert /tmp/(sourcefilename)[0] -quality 80 -strip -profile /app/lib/assets/color_profiles/ISOcoated_v2_bas.ICC -profile /app/lib/assets/color_profiles/sRGBColorSpaceProfile.icm -colorspace sRGB -strip /tmp/(outputfilename).jpg`

And this is how I'm determining the path to the profile files:

`"#{Rack::Directory.new('').root}/lib/assets/color_profiles"`

I'm using Ruby/Rack/Dragonfly and the https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick build pack for Heroku.

Presumably this is because `convert` on Heroku is run from a different location to the app, so the path doesn't resolve correctly.

So - am I doing this right? Is it even possible to give `convert` a path to a file inside my app? Or is this something I need to do at build time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - after a whole day of tinkering, I found the answer myself 34 minutes after posting on SO.

Removing the ImageMagick buildpack and using Heroku's built in version fixes the problem. Looks like it might have been a gap or a bug in the vendored imagemagick build.